# Why get() is not in httpclientmodule?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Stock } from '../shared/models/stock-model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DashboardService {

  readonly url = 'https://apistockssqw.herokuapp.com/bootcamp/stock'

  constructor(private http: HttpClientModule) { }

  async getStock(): Promise<Stock[]>{
    return this.http.get<Stock[]>(`${this.url}/stock`).toPromise();
  }

}
```

this.http.get() is acusing "property 'get' does not exist on type 'HttpClientModule'". Does it mean I should use another import?

Comment: You should import the `HttpClientModule` inside your module and then you should inject `HttpClient` in your service.

Comment: It is already imported in the dashboard module, and it is injected in the service, should I export it from the dashboard module?

Comment: Since you already accepted an answer I assume you figured it out, but to be complete, you should import it inside the imports array of your angular module (the same logic where `providers` and `declarations` are). It is not enough to 'just' `import from`.

Comment: Yeah, it was my mistake, mispelling and the correct imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should inject `HttpClient` in your components/services.

`HttpClientModule` as the name suggests is the module which provides `HttpClient` and should be imported in your application.

Comment: If I use 

import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

does it work?

Comment: The change you have to make is in your constructor: `constructor(private http: HttpClient)`

Answer (score 0):

The module should be in your `app.module.ts`.

In your service, you should import and use `HttpClient` as follow :

```
constructor(private _http: HttpClient){}
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if I import it on the dashboard.module.ts only? If no, why is it not recognizing it?

Comment: @HugoPorfirio  Nah, it just depend on your archi. The important part is that it is a module file